# Implementação de Doctrine 2.5 no Laravel 5.1 usando a configuração do banco de dados mysql

Tags: mysql, doctrine, laravel-5

Comecei a usar o [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) recentemente e consegui configurar quase tudo, mas ao configurar o banco de dados, logo após a instalação do Doctrine, ele me retorna esse erro:

> SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected.

Aparentemente ele está conectando ao banco de dados, mas não está achando a base de dados que configurei.

Está correto:

- Base de dados.
- Credenciais de acesso ao banco.
- Configurado arquivo .env.
- Cache de configuração do artisan limpo.

Basicamente tudo que encontrei em outras perguntas já fiz, mas nada resolve.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão do que eu posso fazer?

Comment: Você não poderia utilizar o próprio ORM do laravel? o eloquent.

Comment: Eu gostaria de usar o Doctrine, porque além de ter mais conhecimento e domínio sobre ele, ele oferece algumas opções a mais do que o nativo. Mas eu desisti e resolvi começar a usar o do laravel mesmo. Infelizmente não tem em lugar algum, documentação suficiente explicando o uso...